# parsing cookie expiration date

Tags: javascript, cookies, momentjs

The expiration date looks fine in Chome dev tools:
[image]

then when i log it it looks like this:
[image]

**My question** is how do i parse it with something like moment.js?

I tried various things with moment, but it's always 1970

```
console.log(moment(1561561645.546124));
// result moment("1970-01-19T03:46:01.645")
```

Comment: new Date(1561561645.546124 * 1000) gives the date.

Comment: LOL it works, but why?

Comment: It expects *microtime* timestamp, 1561561645/1000 = 1561561 = 19days in seconds. which is what your getting `1970-01-19T03:46:01.645`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use epoch time with 13 digit by multiple 1000

You can refer momentjs document, it only support Epoch with millisecond (13 digit)

*Similar to new Date(Number), you can create a moment by passing an integer value representing the number of milliseconds since the Unix Epoch*

https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/unix-timestamp-milliseconds/

```
console.log(moment(1561561645.546124 * 1000));
```

```js
console.log(moment(1561561645.546124 * 1000));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.js" integrity="sha256-H9jAz//QLkDOy/nzE9G4aYijQtkLt9FvGmdUTwBk6gs=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```